# Submitting non-form elements as <span> via form-submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I've got a survey with a few dozens of questions. This survey is divided into multiple parts which are separately submitted via one submit button per part.

Most of the questions should be answered via checkbox. Now i don't want to use  because there are a few issues with its css-styling. Now how do i provide the questions? I've got the follwing approaches:

- Create one span per answer-option, where each span includes a hidden checkbox which is activated when the span is clicked.
- Or ignore the checkbox part and only looked for clicked spans. This seems more clean and less hackier to me, but how do i submit each of the values from multiple clicked spans to my form / php-script?

Comment: From my experience, you need to have the hidden checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as using custom checkboxes made accessible:

- http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/customInput/
- http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201211/accessible_custom_checkboxes_and_radio_buttons/

From the first link:

> *(the checkbox is) positioned directly behind the styled label*

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
data = [];
$('.my-form .ui-mycheckbox.checked').each(function(index, element){
   data.push(element.value);
}
$.post('my-url', data, mycallback);
```

Did not try the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that you could do that, one way is using libraries that allow you to customize elements.

http://customformsjs.com

Allows you to set your custom elements to be spans, divs, anchors or anything that you wish.

Other option is creating hidden inputs and before form submition assigning the value of each accordingly to the span text value.

I personally suggest you using a library like customforms or uniforms since it will degrade to normal form fields if javascript is not enabled on the browser, and it will allow you to customize the styles if javascript is enabled.